# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in GAE basic scaling application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, out-of-memory

I have a java application running on Auto Scaling Google App Engine instance which in turn calls a queue with target application running on Basic Scaling GAE instance. The queue application uses multiple arrays in loops. This is causing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error when the size of data is large. I tried using the clear() method for the arrays for garbage collection but the error still persists. Is there any way to debug Java Heap Space error on GAE or any solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can use a different instance type that is assigned more memory

Comment: can you please post your Code

Comment: Run the same code in local environment, and see if you can reproduce the same problem.